# JSON obj for testing using php / js

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to test my RESTful web service client so I was wondering how I can build a file on my server that will return a JSON object in the following format? In other words, is there a JS / php method / function I could write to help me get the following json obj just by calling the js / php file url?

```
{
   "employees":[
      {
         "id":"20",
         "name":"Vachana"
      },
      {
         "id":"21",
         "name":"Jyosna"
      },
      {
         "id":"22",
         "name":"Avinash"
      }
   ]
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: No need for PHP. Just create a file with that content and put it on your server. You can access it via its URI.

Comment: You can test JSON with JSBin http://jsbin.com/bufig/1

Comment: @FelixKling so just any file with no extension?

Comment: @elclanrs thanks but the format of the json is different, I must have records grouped like in 'employees' as in the example shown in my question

Comment: File extensions don't have any meaning in URLs. You can give the file any extension or none at all. If the file contains JSON, you typically give it the `.json` extension.

Comment: @FelixKling kindly post your last reply as an answer to accept it

Answer (score 0):

As Felix Kling suggests, you do not need to use PHP to format the static output you show. If it is dynamic (perhaps coming from a database), then you could use php to create the array, and then use json_encode to give you the desired output:

```
$output = array();
$output['employees'] = array(
    array('id'=>'20', 'name'=>'Vachana'),
    array('id'=>'21', 'name'=>'Jyosna'),
    array('id'=>'22', 'name'=>'Avinash')
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Brian, thanks but no it is not dynamic, I just want something to test upon